How to limit access to certain type of node?
I am on Drupal 11 and here is my problem:
If I have a node type "article" and another "recipe", I want anonymous users to access only the nodes "article", but not the node "recipe". Only authenticated users should have access to the node types "article" and "recipe". In Drupal 11 the only option in permissions is to see all node types.
How to have the permission to "see published content" for each node type and not for all types ?
Did I look wrong, it's surprising that Drupal 11 is so limited on node permissions, because they are part of the core.

A module with D11 release that provides this feature is:
Entity Bundle Permissions
This module works for any bundleable Content Entity type (this includes node entity type)
Another more lightweight that only targets node types is:
Nodetype Access
Both modules do not have a wide adoption currently, but both have D11 releases.
Another module with a wider adoption, but no D11 release is:
Node View Permissions

it looks good thanks

Which of these modules has the best practice (permission) to integrate best with drupal 11?

Use the Content Access module, which allows you to define which accounts can view, edit, and delete the nodes of each content types.
Steps

Install the module via Composer (composer require drupal/content_access)
Enable the module in your Drupal site (drush en content_access)
Go to Structure > Content types; click Edit for each content type (article and recipe)
Navigate to the Access Control tab (added by the module)
Configure the view/edit/delete permissions for each role
Save the configuration.

This module provides the granularity you're looking for without custom coding.

As OP asked for D11 explicit, it seems Content Access does not have a D11 release already.

There is a dev release of this module available, Which is compatible with Drupal 11. check this https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access/issues/3479745
